# Install .war File on Tomcat, get 503 Error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, tomcat, java, arch-linux

I'm trying to install "YouTrack" on an ArchLinux box with Apache & Tomcat.  I'm totally new to Tomcat though and I'm getting a "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable" error.

I installed Tomcat7 via package manager and put "youtrack.war" into this path: /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/youtrack.war

I modified Tomcat's server.xml here:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

Then in Apache I then configured this:

```
Listen 8081
NameVirtualHost *:8081

<VirtualHost *:8081>
ProxyPass / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/youtrack
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://127.0.0.1:8009/youtrack
</VirtualHost>
```

I then proceeded to restart both services and went to "http://<server>:8081/" and got a 503 error:

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Additionally, a 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

It appears that Tomcat uncompressed the war file into /usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/youtrack/, so I'm pretty sure that's working.

Thanks

*UPDATE*

I added this to virtualhost and it worked:

```
   <Proxy *>
     AddDefaultCharset Off
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
   </Proxy>
```

Comment: Your proxypass rule is for ajp not for http like you have in server.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un-comment the AJP section in tomcat server.xml file and user that port in your vhost section of apache config file. The protocol must be AJP and not HTTP to work.

Comment: Okay I updated my question, I changed it, but still have the same problem.  I appreciate the help so far!